# Yii2 : Add ID tag to gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii2-advanced-app

I've `createCommand` in controller

```
  $receipts=new receipts();
     $query1 = new Query;
     $query1  ->select(['price','date','id']) 
         ->from('paymentreceipts')
         ->join(  'INNER JOIN','patient','patient.patient_id =paymentreceipts.patient_id' )
         ->where('patient.patient_id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))      
         ->orderby ('paymentreceipts.date');
     $command1 = $query1->createCommand();
     $dataProvider1 = $command1->queryAll();  
     $gridViewDataProvider3 = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
     'allModels' => $dataProvider1,
     'sort' => [
     'attributes' => ['price','reg_date','id'],
     ],
     ]);

  return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
         'gridViewDataProvider2' => $gridViewDataProvider2,
    ]);
```

in view.php

```
  <?= 
    GridView::widget([
      'dataProvider' => $gridViewDataProvider2,
      //  'pjax'=>true,    
      'summary'=>'',
      'showFooter' => true,
      'columns' => [
          ['label' => 'رقم الخدمة',
          'attribute' => 'id',
          ],

          [
          //  'label'=>'url',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value'=>function ($data) {
            return Html::a('$data->date','#',['class' => 'receipts','id'=>'id']);
          },
          ],           

          ]
```

]) ?>

what i need is : add the id in  `'attribute' => 'id'` number to the link that i created here `['class' => 'receipts','id'=>'id']);`

i used `'id'=> $gridViewDataProvider2->id` but it doesn't work !

**My English is not good , so maybe my question not be clear .**

Comment: Try: 'id'=> $data->id

Comment: it doesn't work  ,  `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: and $model->id ?

Comment: There is another  grid view in view.php that uses $model ... So it will not give me true Id

Answer (score 1):

**JOIN** statement is the reason why you don't receive "id". Because both of your tables have "id" column and it becomes **ambiguous** to read it. Change you query like below,

```
  $query1  ->select(['price','date','id as receiptId']) 
     ->from('paymentreceipts')
     ->join(  'INNER JOIN','patient','patient.patient_id =paymentreceipts.patient_id' )
     ->where('patient.patient_id=:id', array(':id'=>$id))      
     ->orderby ('paymentreceipts.date');
 $command1 = $query1->createCommand();
```

and then  you can make the link like below.

```
   return Html::a('$data->date','#',['class' => 'receipts','id'=>$data->receiptId]);
```

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object` the problem is the same